# I'm getting an error when trying to compile this constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, atomic, stdatomic

I have a class with a constructor but the compilation fails with the error:

> error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<long unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long unsigned int>&)'

I'm struggling to understand what this error means. I've been trying to update some code from using `tbb::atomic` to using `std::atomic`, and this error wasn't appearing before with `tbb::atomic`.

The bit of code that upsets the compiler is:

```cpp
#include <boost/aligned_storage.hpp>

template <typename T>
class Holder<T,true>
{
public:
  //! Construct a value (there mustn't be one already)
  template <typename ARG>
  void Construct(const ARG &arg) { new(Raw()) T(arg); }

private:
  typename boost::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), boost::alignment_of<T>::value>::type impl;
  void *Raw() { return &impl; }
};
```

Specifically the line:

```cpp
void Construct(const ARG &arg) { new(Raw()) T(arg); }
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me understand what is going on.

**EDIT:**

Full error message:

```
holder.hpp:75:34: error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<long unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long unsigned int>&)'
   75 |   void Construct(const T &arg) { new(Raw()) T(arg); }
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /include/TPtools/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_std_atomic.hpp:19,
                 from /include/TPtools/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp:48,
                 from /include/TPtools/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:29,
                 from /include/TPtools/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from /include/TPtools/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from movegate.cpp:14:
/pkgsData/gcc-v9.3.0p1/Linux/RHEL6.0-2013-x86_64/include/c++/9.3.0/atomic:824:7: note: declared here
  824 |       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~
holder.hpp: In instantiation of 'void Holder<T, true>::Construct(const T&) [with T = std::atomic<long unsigned int>; T = std::atomic<long unsigned int>]':
element.hpp:185:9:   required from 'void Element<PRESENT, ABSENT>::Accessor<PRESENCE>::MakePresentImpl(const ARG&) const [with ARG = std::atomic<long unsigned int>; PRESENCE = Cluster<Element<std::atomic<long unsigned int>, Link>, true>::NonLockingPresence; PRESENT = std::atomic<long unsigned int>; ABSENT = Link]'
element.hpp:119:7:   required from 'Element<PRESENT, ABSENT>::PresentResult Element<PRESENT, ABSENT>::Accessor<PRESENCE>::MakePresent(const ARG&) const [with ARG = std::atomic<long unsigned int>; PRESENCE = Cluster<Element<std::atomic<long unsigned int>, Link>, true>::NonLockingPresence; PRESENT = std::atomic<long unsigned int>; ABSENT = Link; Element<PRESENT, ABSENT>::PresentResult = std::atomic<long unsigned int>&]'
dispenser.hpp:78:5:   required from 'Index Dispenser<T>::Insert(const T&) [with T = std::atomic<long unsigned int>]'
```

Comment: Where in this code do `atomic`s of any sort come up? I assume one of the template values somewhere, but which?

Comment: Please show the _entire_ error message. If you're using Visual Studio, the entire error message is in the "output" pane, and NOT the "error" pane.
Specifically, We need to see the template parameter to the `Construct` method.

Comment: Also maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, for handy advice about how to word the title, and other useful information to put in a question.

Comment: I _speculate_ you're instantiating a `Holder<std::atomic<long>>`, but `std::atomic<long>` is not copiable, and `Construct` can _only_ copy-construct, making them incompatible. But I can't confirm that guess without more code or more of the error message.

Comment: Sorry. First-time poster, inexperienced programmer! I've put more of the error output in. I hope that helps.

Comment: As the error message says, `Contruct()` is being called with `T` and `ARG` both set to `std::atomic<long unsigned int>`, thus you end up with `void Construct(const std::atomic<long unsigned int> &arg) { new(Raw()) std::atomic<long unsigned int>(arg); }`, which does not work because `std::atomic` can't be copied (its copy constructor is `delete`'d), so you will have to either move-construct it: `template <typename ARG> void Construct(ARG &&arg) { new(Raw()) T(std::move(arg)); }` or maybe perfect-forwarding: `template <typename ARG> void Construct(ARG &&arg) { new(Raw()) T(std::forward(arg)); }`